# How to read the lambda syntax in Koin factory DSL?

Tags: android, kotlin, koin

I recently started looking in to the Koin di library and I am very confused about this code snippet:

```kotlin
factory<FeatureContract.Presenter<Student>> { (view: FeatureContract.View<Student>) ->
        FeaturePresenter(view)
}
```

Specifically this part:

```kotlin
(view: FeatureContract.View<Student>) ->
        FeaturePresenter(view)

// Why not the following?
{ view ->
       FeaturePresenter(view)
}
```

I am very confused about the Koin DSL syntax here. As you can see this is a lambda like structure with lambda arguments in parentheses (How?). Which I had a very hard time reason about. Why does the lambda expression here has argument in the parentheses instead of outside the parentheses? Is this some kind of syntax I wasn't aware of? Please let me know, thanks.

Comment: It’s just optional type arguments in optional parenthesis. Probably supposed to make the example clearer … ironically.

Comment: `{ FeaturePresenter(it) }` would be idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks, I still don't really get it, but with what you have commented it seems to have something to do with "typealias" - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/type-aliases.html I am going to read about it

Comment: No. It’s not a type alias. It’s simply a type. You can write a variable as `x` or `x: String` to be explicit.

Comment: I don't think so, since that only apply to example like this ```val example1 = { x: String -> println(x)}``` but not ```val example2 = { (x: String) -> println(x) }``` with the parentheses, it is not a valid lambda syntax. Instead I feel this has more things related to typealise ```public typealias Definition<T> = (org.koin.core.parameter.ParameterList) -> T```

Comment: Or this ```typealias MyHandler = (Int, String, Any) -> Unit``` from the kotlin docs